# IOS TableView not responding to last row code

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uiscrollview

I am using swift 3 and have a TableView, am I trying to fire a particular piece of code when the user is in the last row. For some reason it is completely ignoring that and not firing off . I have even put a breakpoint there and it does not hit it. This is what I have

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

      if indexPath.row == self.Locations.count   {
           print("Last Row")
      } 
}
```

The print statement is not showing neither is the breakpoint . My TableView code is this

```
class HomePageC: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var TableSource: UITableView!
var Locations = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    TableSource.allowsSelection = false
    TableSource.dataSource = self
    TableSource.estimatedRowHeight = 504
    TableSource.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    TableSource.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

    TableSource.tableFooterView = UIView()

}

func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
     // This always returns 10 items
     return Locations.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
     UITableViewCell {
  // This just populates the fields as I have a custom TableView
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you verified whether `willDisplay()` is being called? I suspect is isn't. `func tableView(UITableView, willDisplay: UITableViewCell, forRowAt: IndexPath)` is a `UITableViewDelegate` method. Your table view will not know to call it until you set it's delegate property, but I do not see where this is being done.

The delegate can be set in `viewDidLoad()`, just as you are doing for the `dataSource` property:

```
TableSource.delegate = self
```

You will also need to declare that `HomePageC` adopts the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol. This can be done in the class declaration:

```
class HomePageC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that is exactly what I was missing, everything is working now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for equality against `self.Locations.count - 1`. Since indexing starts from 0, the last item's `indexPath.row` will be 9 while Locations.count is 10.

```
        if indexPath.row == self.Locations.count - 1 {
            print("Last Row")
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
if indexPath.row == (self.Locations.count - 1)   {
    print("Last Row")
}
```

Its because count returns the number of items in the array, where as the index path returns the iteration, which starts at 0